# Create square image ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

My goal is to scale an image so its smallest dimension is 300 and keep the aspect ratio of the other, and then crop to 300x300.

Effectivley, the goal of this is to take a 300x300 thumbnail of as much of the image as I can while keeping the aspect ratio solid before i do the crop

Goal: scale and crop image to 300x300

Ive determined the following cases. How can I accomplish this in ffmpeg?
5 cases:

```
height > width; both > 300
    scale=-1:300
height < width; both > 300
    scale=300:-1
height < 300
    scale=300:-1
width < 300
    scale=-1:300
height <300 && width < 300
    scale=300:300
```

Answer (score 1):

The scale filter has an option to enforce a minimum or maximum resolution while keeping proportions.

Use

```
scale=300:300:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=300:300
```

The scale filter will scale the input to the smallest resolution which is at least 300x300.